# C++ count occurence of the word from a file and write to another file

Tags: c++, file

What is the problem in this code?
I am trying to search for the word TID in input.txt 
input.txt-

TID TID
 TID:fjkcgbkn

It just shows 0 in output.txt

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int con=0;
ifstream fi;
fi.open("input.txt");
char word[3];

  while(!fi.eof())
  {
     fi.get(word,3,' ');
     if (strcmp(word,"TID") == 0)
        con++;
  }
  fi.close();

ofstream fo;
fo.open ("output.txt");
fo<<con<<"\n";
fo.close();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you at least need to resize `word` to [4], as there's no room for the NULL terminator '\0'.  Simply adding that and it might just work.

Comment: this code is not very flexible...if you need to change the delimiter to something else your code will not work anymore. you usually implement a state-machine and check character by character :)

Comment: Your code also doesn't finish running for me in VS, it's stuck in an infinite loop. You need to check `fi.good()`, not `!fi.eof()`.

Answer (score 2):

Is because when you use quotation mark like this:

```
"TID"
```

in memory is saved like this

```
TID\0
```

where \0 is mark of the end of string.

You could add to your variable `word` at the end '\0' and it should work (change size to 4:)

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

First, `word` must be 4 bytes long in order to hold the null terminator that `ifstream::get` reads:

```
char word[4];
```

Second, the buffer size passed to `fi.get()` must be updated to match:

```
fi.get(word,4,' ')
```

[As per documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/), `ifstream::get(char*,streamsize,char)` will read `n-1` characters at most, then append a null terminator. This will let you read the full 3 character string plus its terminator. (Using `sizeof(word)` instead of `4` is also an option; it will allow you to change the size of `word` without having to modify anything else.)

Note that you are still going to produce incorrect results for strings like `"abTID TID"`, which will first read `"abT"` then `"ID"`. Necessary improvements to the algorithm are left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 1):

Here a way (not tested, but should work):

```
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

ifstream fin("input.txt");
ofstream fout("output.txt", std::ios::trunc);
fin >> noskipws;
istream_iterator<string> iter(fin), end;
ostream_iterator<string> iter_out(fout);

int count = 0;
copy_if(iter, end, iter_out, [&count](string const & val) -> bool 
 { if (val == "TID") {
       ++count;
       return true;
   }
   return false;
});
```

Comment: This is certainly a way to do it but it does not directly address or explain the errors the OP was seeing.

Comment: I voted you up. Your point is right. But I wanted to illustrate a solution, since what he wants to do after all is this.

Comment: @JasonC It addresses the errors by removing them, which is good a good thing: the standard library gives you tools that make it harder to make simple mistakes, it is good to know these. +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

Alernatively to the function **get()**, you must use the function **getline()**.

It will solve the problem of your \0 null character.

*These are the most basics you must have learned in file handling in C++.*